# array required but [ClassName] found java

Tags: java, arrays, equality

I'm trying to write a function checking if 2 arrays are equal.

```
public class DynamicArray {
    private int size; // stores the number of “occupied” elements in the array
    private int[] array; 

    ...

    boolean equals(DynamicArray obj) {
        boolean keepChecking = true;
        int objSize = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i] == 0 && keepChecking) {
                keepChecking = false;
                objSize = obj[i];
            }
        }

        if (size != objSize) 
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (array [i] != obj [i]) {
               return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The thing is that array might be partially filled array, not filled elements will be just zeros. So, to check if 2 arrays are equal, first, I find the size of the occupied array and then I do all the checkings.

So, every time I'm trying to get the value of obj[i] or obj.length it keeps showing the error "array required, but DynamicArray found." for obj[i] and "cannot find symbol \n symbol: variable length \n location: variable obj of type DynamicArray" which I don't understand because the other array is also DynamicArray type

```
public class ArrayDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynamicArray ar1 = new DynamicArray(1);
        DynamicArray ar2 = new DynamicArray(1);

        System.out.println("equals() is " + ar1.equals(ar2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Does order matter, woud say {'A','B','C'} and {'C','A','B'} considered equal?

Comment: @AndrewS yes, I want to check if they are exactly the same

Comment: `obj` doesn't refer to an array, it refers to your class `DynamicArray`, so I would assume instead of `obj[i]`, you would need `obj.array[i]`

Comment: @AndrewS True, as to if I would call it "standard practice" is a matter of opinion ;)

Comment: @In43sh on what line does this error occour?

Comment: @AndrewS the first error is on line **for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {** but all of the lines where I'm trying to access obj[i] or obj.length are highlighted red.

Comment: @AndrewS But the OP is not overriding the method, they are providing another which does similar or same functionality with formal parameters

Comment: True, it is not standard practice to use a datatype other than Object with an equals method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter obj in the equals method is not an array but an instance of DynamicArray. Therefore you cannot access the values with the [] on the identifier obj. You need to rewrite that method. You also need to include methods for setting and getting the elements of the array in your DynamicArray object. For example:

val = ar1.get(0);

and

ar1.set(0, value);

So this means your Dynamic array needs the following two methods (I am assuming the values of your array are ints, but this could be anything). I'll let you figure out what goes in them as I see you must be learning the language.

```
public void set(int index, int value){
}

public int get(int index){
}
```

That way you can then use your methods in your rewritten equals function to access the elements of the array.

Another tip. You would be better sorting both arrays. Compare the first element or each, then the next, and then the next until such time you find a mismatch. At that point you can return false. If you find no mismatch return true.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is , DynamicArray is not an array, its a class, you have to define a length function of it.you can just call obj.length wich is DynamicArray class which has no method length